# How to install Big blue button on centos

Tags: xubuntu, kvm-virtualization

I want to install bigbluebutton on centos but I did not found any documentation about it, one tutorial I found that to install ubuntu server then install bbb on it. Now my question is, Is it possible to install ubuntu server on centOS if it is possible then please any one give me docs to how to install ubuntu server on centOS.

Comment: Ubuntu and CentOS are operating systems and not programmes that can be installed. You want to make use of bigbluebutton, go to their site and read the FAQs and manuals which normally give a hint on which operating system the app will work best. Best also would be to contact the guys from bbb for install issues.

Comment: On the matter of closing this topic, it would appear that this would be the best place for a novice user to be introduced on how to install and run Ubuntu.  The Centos channel would probably, understandably send him to Ubuntu support for the task.

Answer (score 4):

**Centos** and **Ubuntu** are operating systems.  You don't install an Operating system into a different one.  You install applications into Operating systems.

You would either replace **Centos** with **Ubuntu** by installing Ubuntu on top of your **Centos**.  Follow the prompts in the Ubuntu installation disk.  The options include:

1. **Install Ubuntu on the whole disk.**
   This will reformat your disk where you will only have Ubuntu.  You would loose your previous files.  So using this option you should be sure to have your important data backed up.
2. **Install alongside previous OS**
   This will give you a graphical interface where you can use a slider to divide the space using by your previous OS.  After this install you will have both installed.  When you boot you will have a menu to choose which OS to use.  This will not overwrite/remove your previous data.
3. **Do Something else**
   **(a)** During this install you will have an option to choose which partition to install Ubuntu.  You could choose the same partition of a previous Linux Distro.  This will not overwrite data in your personal space `/home`.  It will replace the folders that are part of the Operating system, such as `/usr/bin`, `/bin`, `/etc`, and so on.  **(b)** On this same option you could also specify a different Partition to install Ubuntu.  If you specify a different partition, it won't touch your previuos install.  The whole OS will be installed on the specificed partition.  After installation you will have a chance of which OS to boot to.

**Install Ubuntu in a VM**

Alternatively you can install **Virtualbox** or a different virtualization package.  This will allow you to create Virtual Machines on your current OS where you can run the full Ubuntu OS from there.

Comment: I developed Moodle based LMS website in this site requirement is install plugin Big Blue Button (Online video class). My site is hosted on linux server (centos). I have only shell to install something on server. so bigbluebutton all documentation tells installation of bbb on Ubuntu but I found this ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6Saztv2WlKI ), in this tut he install ubuntu then he install bbb.

Comment: @omair As mentioned in the comments, if you are trying to have support for **Ubuntu** you are in the right place.  It's on topic.  But for support outside of **Ubuntu** it is off topic, and would belong in one of our other forums.  I addressed the part of your question that refers to **Install Ubuntu Server**.  The users voting to close were based on the question's title **Install Big Blue Button on CENTOS** which is off topic here.  If you want to use **Ubuntu** because of the ease you mention, we can help with that part only.

Comment: We can help you with your issue.  You will first have to tell us which version of Ubuntu you have installed.  The install methods are in my answer.  Outside of running Ubuntu is off topic.